# Transcoding UTF-8 to UTF-16-LE in VBA

Tags: performance, vba, unicode, utf-8

VBA is a language that's lacking a lot of basic functionality. (Pun intended)
Most libraries, if they exist in the first place, are OS-specific, and even some of the inbuilt functions don't work on MacOS or have bugs in any environment.

Recently I've found that the `StrConv(s, vbUnicode)` function transcoding a string to the VBA-internal UTF-16-LE encoding doesn't properly work in all environments and for all Unicode codepoints. Therefore, I simply implemented my own function for this task. ([SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75787820/12287457))

Since this is a fairly low-level task, I was trying to be efficient and to make the code as performant as possible by working on a single byte-array buffer and avoiding things like string concatenation which may be tempting here.

I ended up with this code which pretty much fits my needs. I'm sure though, there are still opportunities for improvement, and I have been asked to post it here for review so here you go.

```vb
Function DecodeUTF8(ByVal utf8str As String) As String
    Dim utf8() As Byte, utf16() As Byte, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim codePoint As Long, cpIndex As Long, numBytesOfCodePoint As Long
    utf8 = utf8str
    ReDim utf16(0 To (UBound(utf8) - LBound(utf8) + 1) * 2)
    i = LBound(utf8): cpIndex = 0
    Do While i <= UBound(utf8)
        'Determine the number of bytes in the current UTF-8 codepoint
        numBytesOfCodePoint = 1
        If utf8(i) And &H80 Then
            If utf8(i) And &H20 Then
                If utf8(i) And &H10 Then
                    numBytesOfCodePoint = 4
                Else: numBytesOfCodePoint = 3: End If
            Else: numBytesOfCodePoint = 2: End If
        End If
    
        'Check if the UTF-8 codepoint is incomplete at the end of the string
        If i + numBytesOfCodePoint - 1 > UBound(utf8) Then Err.Raise 5, _
            "DecodeUtf8", _
            "Incomplete UTF-8 codepoint at the end of the input string."
    
        'Calculate the Unicode codepoint value from the UTF-8 bytes
        If numBytesOfCodePoint = 1 Then
            codePoint = utf8(i)
        Else
            codePoint = utf8(i) And (2 ^ (7 - numBytesOfCodePoint) - 1)
            For j = 1 To numBytesOfCodePoint - 1
                codePoint = (codePoint * 64) + (utf8(i + j) And &H3F)
            Next j
        End If
    
        'Convert the Unicode codepoint to UTF-16LE bytes
        If codePoint < &H10000 Then
            utf16(cpIndex) = CByte(codePoint And &HFF&)
            utf16(cpIndex + 1) = CByte(codePoint \ &H100&)
            cpIndex = cpIndex + 2
        Else 'Calculate surrogate pair
            Dim m As Long, lowSurrogate As Long, highSurrogate As Long
            m = codePoint - &H10000
            '(m \ &H400&) = most significant 10 bits of m
            highSurrogate = &HD800& + (m \ &H400&)
            '(m And &H3FF) = least significant 10 bits of m
            lowSurrogate = &HDC00& + (m And &H3FF)
            'Concatenate highSurrogate and lowSurrogate as UTF-16LE bytes
            utf16(cpIndex) = CByte(highSurrogate And &HFF&)
            utf16(cpIndex + 1) = CByte(highSurrogate \ &H100&)
            utf16(cpIndex + 2) = CByte(lowSurrogate And &HFF&)
            utf16(cpIndex + 3) = CByte(lowSurrogate \ &H100&)
            cpIndex = cpIndex + 4
        End If
        i = i + numBytesOfCodePoint 'Move to the next UTF-8 codepoint
    Loop
    ReDim Preserve utf16(cpIndex - 1)
    DecodeUTF8 = utf16
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great work, as usual, definitely needed for Mac compatibility and nice as a learning exercise.

##### Buffer

I don't think there is a way to improve on the Byte buffer approach. After all, the maximum number of bytes would be twice as many if all the codepoints are less than 128 i.e. one byte per codepoint.

An idea would be to replace these 2 lines:

```
ReDim Preserve utf16(cpIndex - 1)
DecodeUTF8 = utf16
```

with:

```
DecodeUTF8 = MidB$(utf16, 1, cpIndex)
```

but with no performance gain as there is already a conversion going on when passing the array argument as string. We're just saving a line of code.

However, a good improvement would be to have the buffer as an `Integer` array instead of `Byte` because then all codepoints and surrogates would be simply assigned to the array with no need to mask with `codePoint And &HFF&` or bit shift with `codePoint \ &H100&`. However, this will require some `CopyMemory` API calls. No time to do that now but I might return with a later edit.

##### Performance

Raising to power as in `(2 ^ (7 - numBytesOfCodePoint) - 1)` is a costly operation. We could use a static array of pre-calculated powers of 2 which can be used as a lookup.

We could also use a static array to store the number of bytes needed per codepoint and remove the need to have many `If` statements.

Somethig like:

```
Static byteCount(0 To 255) As Byte
Dim i As Long

If byteCount(0) = 0 Then
    For i = &H0 To &H7F  '0xxxxxxx
        byteCount(i) = 1
    Next i
    For i = &HC0 To &HDF '110xxxxx
        byteCount(i) = 2
    Next i
    For i = &HE0 To &HEF '1110xxxx
        byteCount(i) = 3
    Next i
    For i = &HF0 To &HF7 '11110xxx
        byteCount(i) = 4
    Next i
End If
```

and now every first byte of each codepoint can be looked up in the array with something like:
`bytesPerCode = byteCount(firstCPByte)`. A result of 0 would raise an invalid byte error.

##### Invalid sequence

You already have error handling in place in case the sequence is incomplete. However there are other issues that need to be addressed. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Invalid_sequences_and_error_handling) Wikipedia article lists a few:

> - invalid bytes
> - an unexpected continuation byte
> - a non-continuation byte before the end of the character
> - the string ending before the end of the character (which can happen in simple string truncation)
> - an overlong encoding
> - a sequence that decodes to an invalid code point

For example a byte value of 128 (&H80) should be flagged as invalid but in the current approach this passes as valid on the `Else: numBytesOfCodePoint = 2: End If` branch.

Another example: a byte value of 11000010 (&HC2) denotes a 2-byte codepoint and the second byte should be of the form 10xxxxxx but in the current approach something like 11000000 passes as a valid continuation byte.

The static `byteCount` array presented in the **Performance** section already covers nicely for invalid first bytes.

For 2 bytes per codepoint we can avoid overlong encoding by marking C0 and C1 as invalid directly in the static array i.e replace `For i = &HC0 To &HDF` with `For i = &HC2 To &HDF` because we know that 110xxxxx 10xxxxxx must already exclude anything below value 128.

For 3 and 4 bytes we can check for overlong encoding after codepoint has been calculated with something like:

```
If bytesPerCode = 3 And codePoint < &H800& Then
    Err.Raise 5, methodName, "Overlong encoding"
ElseIf bytesPerCode = 4 And codePoint < &H10000 Then
    Err.Raise 5, methodName, "Overlong encoding"
End If
```

Or, we could just have another static array with the accepted limits and call it like this:

```
If codePoint < minCodePoint(bytesPerCode) Then
    Err.Raise 5, methodName, "Overlong encoding"
End If
```

Of course, we could cover 2 bytes per code point directly from the static array without needing to exclude C0 and C1 from the `byteCount` static array as mentioned above.

##### Solution

The solution presented below performs about 35% faster than the original solution presented in the question and this is thanks to the lookups using the static arrays. I've renamed the function name as a personal preference although `DecodeUTF8` is perfectly fine.

```
Public Function UTF8ToUTF16LE(ByRef utf8Text As String) As String
    Const methodName As String = "UTF8ToUTF16LE"
    Dim bytesCount As Long: bytesCount = LenB(utf8Text)
    If bytesCount = 0 Then Exit Function
    '
    Dim utf8() As Byte:  utf8 = utf8Text
    Dim utf16() As Byte: ReDim utf16(0 To bytesCount * 2 - 1)
    '
    Static byteCount(0 To 255) As Long
    Static mask(3 To 5) As Long
    Static minCodePoint(2 To 4) As Long
    Dim i As Long
    '
    If byteCount(0) = 0 Then
        For i = &H0& To &H7F&  '0xxxxxxx
            byteCount(i) = 1
        Next i
        For i = &HC2& To &HDF& '110xxxxx - C0 and C1 are invalid (overlong encoding)
            byteCount(i) = 2
        Next i
        For i = &HE0& To &HEF& '1110xxxx
            byteCount(i) = 3
        Next i
        For i = &HF0& To &HF3& '11110xxx - 111101xx is not valid according to RFC 3629 to match UTF-16 limits
            byteCount(i) = 4
        Next i
        For i = 3 To 5
            mask(i) = 2 ^ i - 1
        Next i
        minCodePoint(2) = &H80&
        minCodePoint(3) = &H800&
        minCodePoint(4) = &H10000
    End If
    '
    Dim codePoint As Long
    Dim bytesPerCode As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim loByte As Byte
    Dim bufferIndex As Long: bufferIndex = 0
    '
    i = 0
    Do
        codePoint = utf8(i)
        bytesPerCode = byteCount(codePoint)
        '
        If bytesPerCode = 0 Then
            Err.Raise 5, methodName, "Invalid byte"
        ElseIf bytesPerCode = 1 Then
            utf16(bufferIndex) = codePoint
            bufferIndex = bufferIndex + 2
        ElseIf i + bytesPerCode > bytesCount Then
            Err.Raise 5, methodName, "Incomplete character"
        Else
            codePoint = codePoint And mask(7 - bytesPerCode)
            For j = 1 To bytesPerCode - 1
                loByte = utf8(i + j)
                If (loByte And &HC0&) <> &H80& Then '10xxxxxx
                    Err.Raise 5, methodName, "Invalid continuation byte"
                End If
                codePoint = codePoint * &H40& + (loByte And &H3F&)
            Next j
            If codePoint < minCodePoint(bytesPerCode) Then
                Err.Raise 5, methodName, "Overlong encoding"
            End If
            '
            'Convert from Unicode codepoint to UTF-16LE bytes
            If bytesPerCode < 4 Then
                utf16(bufferIndex) = CByte(codePoint And &HFF&)
                utf16(bufferIndex + 1) = CByte(codePoint \ &H100&)
                bufferIndex = bufferIndex + 2
            Else
                Dim m As Long:             m = codePoint - &H10000
                Dim lowSurrogate As Long:  lowSurrogate = &HDC00& + (m And &H3FF&)
                Dim highSurrogate As Long: highSurrogate = &HD800& + (m \ &H400&)
                '
                utf16(bufferIndex) = CByte(highSurrogate And &HFF&)
                utf16(bufferIndex + 1) = CByte(highSurrogate \ &H100&)
                utf16(bufferIndex + 2) = CByte(lowSurrogate And &HFF&)
                utf16(bufferIndex + 3) = CByte(lowSurrogate \ &H100&)
                bufferIndex = bufferIndex + 4
            End If
        End If
        i = i + bytesPerCode
    Loop Until i >= bytesCount
    UTF8ToUTF16LE = MidB$(utf16, 1, bufferIndex)
End Function
```

Comment: Great points you are making! I knew the operations you mentioned were costly but I didn't think of the brilliant array trick! I was aware that my solution allows invalid encodings, I already knew the article you linked, but I thought it would be too complicated to account for all of that and also I expect only correct UTF-8 inputs for my use-case. I agree that for a general-purpose function, it should definitely be taken into account, and will update my SO answer. I might even add a BOM check. Regarding 16bit buffer: I prefer no API calls at a slight performance cost for better portability.